# Why some of new indexed pages of my web site disappeared from search results?

Tags: seo, google-search

10 days ago i have activated my web-site with whole new design and content and because of it's an old web site and has 2 pr, it's quickly added to search results by google.

Then i sent some important url's to google via webmasters tools for make google index those pages. After 2-3 days those pages were indexed.

But i realized those pages are disappearing from index and today all sub-pages disappeared.

There aren't any spammy content, pages were original, valid html5 code.

What can be the cause of this ?

Answer (score 1):

as a start id check to see wether the page is still indexed by searching site:www.example.com

i had somthing like this happen quite recently, after about 2 weeks the rankings where back to normal (some fell a few places, some gained a few)

Comment: weirdest part is there are removed pages still can be seen on the search results. all removed pages are redirected to the main page by 301 redirect code and also some folders have disallow command in robots.txt. these pages are still in the search results but the pages which supposed to be in search results are removed. wtf ?

btw, i have seen some messages about this issue and some of them mentioned it's a temporarily problem and can be fixed without doing nothing.

i was thinking not linking from main page can be the cause of this problem but i'm not sure.

Comment: have you removed the pages with the url removal tool in webmaster, or just deleted them from the site ? Can you confirm if the pages that "went missing" show up when you search site:http://www.example.com

Comment: old pages redirected via 301 code to the main page and some of folders added to robots.txt as "disallow" crawling but they are still can be seen when i tried to search site:mysite.com but new pages, the pages should can be seen, are not. they are removed.

Comment: that's weird but removed pages are added to search results. i did nothing.